# Puzzled as to why .done() not passing in the jqXHR object?

Tags: jquery, ajax, responsetext

```
var theRequest = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    method: 'GET',
}).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(theRequest.responseText);
  });
```

Is my understanding correct that the `data` that is passed in to the function within  the `.done()` method should be the `jqXHR` object that is returned from the `$.ajax()` request?

I thought the below code would work but it doesn't because `data` does not have a `responseText` property, which I thought it would because I thought it should be the `jqXHR` object returned from the `$.ajax()` request?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    method: 'GET',
}).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.responseText);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct that the data that is passed in to the function within the .done() method should be the jqXHR object that is returned from the $.ajax() request?

No, `data` will be the data returned by the request. From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

> **jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});**
>
> An alternative construct to the `success` callback option, the `.done()` method replaces the deprecated `jqXHR.success()` method. Refer to `deferred.done()` for implementation details.

...which I'll grant is less than thorough. :-) But note the three arguments in the function signature shown: `data`, `textStatus`, and `jqXHR`. These are the same as for the `success` function if you use it in the options, so the documentation for them is useful:

> Type: `Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )`
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The `data` returned from the server, formatted according to the `dataType` parameter or the `dataFilter` callback function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the `jqXHR` (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

Answer (score 3):

The `.done()` method receives three arguments: `data`, `textStatus`, and `jqXHR`. `data` is the response from the AJAX request; if you use `dataType: 'json'`, it will be the object that results from parsing the JSON.

The `responseText` property is in the `jqXHR` parameter. It should be:

```
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

The two log messages should be the same.

Comment: *"The two log messages should be the same."* That'll depend on the `Content-Type` header from the server; `data` gets pre-processed if it's JSON or XML and you don't override that with `dataType`.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the `.done` prototype, the 3rd parameter will be `jqXHR` whereas first parameter will be `data` returned as response.

```
jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});
```

> An alternative construct to the success callback option, the .done()
>   method replaces the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to
>   **[`deferred.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)** for implementation details.

**[Source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

`.done` is alternative for `.success` as mentioned in the docs.

So you can fetch `jqXHR` if you include it as 3rd parameter in `.done`